# How to maintain zookeeper ensemble?

Tags: zookeeper

I have a 3 node zookeeper ensemble running from where I had trouble with one node showing a corrupt db. Now I found in the docs that it has to be cleared regularily with the help of cron running this command:

> java -cp zookeeper.jar:log4j.jar:conf org.apache.zookeeper.server.PurgeTxnLog /var/lib/zookeeper/ /var/lib/zookeeper/version-2/ -n 3

Unfortunatelly I do get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
>       at org.apache.zookeeper.server.PurgeTxnLog.(PurgeTxnLog.java:45)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 1 more

What is causing this and how could I prevent zookeeper from corrupting the db again due to too many log entries?

Answer (score 2):

slf4j's jars are missing from classpath; you can add them manually, but it's better to use `zkCleanup.sh` (comes with zookeeper) instead.